# Rendering German Umlauts with SpriteFont in C++ using SDL_ttf

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a SpriteFont class that uses `SDL_ttf` to render letters to the screen. Currently, my program supports ASCII characters from 32 to 126. However, as I need to support German umlauts, I want to extend the range to include ASCII characters up to 154.

Specifically, I need assistance in rendering German umlauts correctly. When I increase the value for `_LAST_PRINTABLE_CHAR_` (to include ASCII values for umlauts, such as 154), the program crashes. I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding how to render umlauts correctly on the screen.

**Here is the SpriteFont-Class:**

SpriteFont.h:

```
/* 
This is a modified version of the SpriteFont class from the
Seed Of Andromeda source code.
Use it for any of your projects, commercial or otherwise,
free of charge, but do not remove this disclaimer.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS
ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO
EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT,
INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER
RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION,
ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE
OF THIS SOFTWARE.

November 28 2014
Original Author: Cristian Zaloj
Modified By: Benjamin Arnold
*/

#pragma once

#ifndef SpriteFont_h__
#define SpriteFont_h__

#include <TTF/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include "Vertex.h"

namespace Bengine {

    struct GLTexture;
    class SpriteBatch;

    struct CharGlyph {
    public:
        char character;
        glm::vec4 uvRect;
        glm::vec2 size;
    };

#define FIRST_PRINTABLE_CHAR ((char)32)
#define LAST_PRINTABLE_CHAR ((char)126)

    /// For text justification
    enum class Justification {
        LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT
    };

    class SpriteFont {
    public:
        SpriteFont() {};
        SpriteFont(const char* font, int size, char cs, char ce);
        SpriteFont(const char* font, int size) :
            SpriteFont(font, size, FIRST_PRINTABLE_CHAR, LAST_PRINTABLE_CHAR) {
        }

        void init(const char* font, int size);
        void init(const char* font, int size, char cs, char ce);
    
        /// Destroys the font resources
        void dispose();

        int getFontHeight() const {
            return _fontHeight;
        }

        /// Measures the dimensions of the text
        glm::vec2 measure(const char* s);

        /// Draws using a spritebatch
        void draw(SpriteBatch& batch, const char* s, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 scaling, 
              float depth, ColorRGBA8 tint, Justification just = Justification::LEFT);
    private:
        static std::vector<int>* createRows(glm::ivec4* rects, int rectsLength, int r, int padding, int& w);

        int _regStart, _regLength;
        CharGlyph* _glyphs;
        int _fontHeight;

        unsigned int _texID;
    };
}
#endif // SpriteFont_h__
```

SpriteFont.cpp:

```
#include "SpriteFont.h"

#include "SpriteBatch.h"

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>


int closestPow2(int i) {
    i--;
    int pi = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        i >>= 1;
        pi <<= 1;
    }
    return pi;
}

#define MAX_TEXTURE_RES 4096

namespace Bengine {

    SpriteFont::SpriteFont(const char* font, int size, char cs, char ce) {
        init(font, size, cs, ce);
    }

    void SpriteFont::init(const char* font, int size) {
        init(font, size, FIRST_PRINTABLE_CHAR, LAST_PRINTABLE_CHAR);
    }

    void SpriteFont::init(const char* font, int size, char cs, char ce) {
        // Initialize SDL_ttf
        if (!TTF_WasInit()) {
            TTF_Init();
        }
        TTF_Font* f = TTF_OpenFont(font, size);
        if (f == nullptr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open TTF font %s\n", font);
            fflush(stderr);
            throw 281;
        }
        _fontHeight = TTF_FontHeight(f);
        _regStart = cs;
        _regLength = ce - cs + 1;
        int padding = size / 8;

        std::cout << _regStart << " " << _regLength << std::endl;
        // First neasure all the regions
        glm::ivec4* glyphRects = new glm::ivec4[_regLength];
        int i = 0, advance;
        for (char c = cs; c <= ce; c++) {
            TTF_GlyphMetrics(f, c, &glyphRects[i].x, &glyphRects[i].z, &glyphRects[i].y, &glyphRects[i].w, &advance);
            glyphRects[i].z -= glyphRects[i].x;
            glyphRects[i].x = 0;
            glyphRects[i].w -= glyphRects[i].y;
            glyphRects[i].y = 0;
            i++;
        }

        // Find best partitioning of glyphs
        int rows = 1, w, h, bestWidth = 0, bestHeight = 0, area = MAX_TEXTURE_RES * MAX_TEXTURE_RES, bestRows = 0;
        std::vector<int>* bestPartition = nullptr;
        while (rows <= _regLength) {
            h = rows * (padding + _fontHeight) + padding;
            auto gr = createRows(glyphRects, _regLength, rows, padding, w);

            // Desire a power of 2 texture
            w = closestPow2(w);
            h = closestPow2(h);

            // A texture must be feasible
            if (w > MAX_TEXTURE_RES || h > MAX_TEXTURE_RES) {
                rows++;
                delete[] gr;
                continue;
            }

            // Check for minimal area
            if (area >= w * h) {
                if (bestPartition) delete[] bestPartition;
                bestPartition = gr;
                bestWidth = w;
                bestHeight = h;
                bestRows = rows;
                area = bestWidth * bestHeight;
                rows++;
            }
            else {
                delete[] gr;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Can a bitmap font be made?
        if (!bestPartition) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to Map TTF font %s to texture. Try lowering resolution.\n", font);
            fflush(stderr);
            throw 282;
        }
        // Create the texture
        glGenTextures(1, &_texID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bestWidth, bestHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

        // Now draw all the glyphs
        SDL_Color fg = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
        int ly = padding;
        for (int ri = 0; ri < bestRows; ri++) {
            int lx = padding;
            for (size_t ci = 0; ci < bestPartition[ri].size(); ci++) {
                int gi = bestPartition[ri][ci];

                SDL_Surface* glyphSurface = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(f, (char)(cs + gi), fg);

                // Pre-multiplication occurs here
                unsigned char* sp = (unsigned char*)glyphSurface->pixels;
                int cp = glyphSurface->w * glyphSurface->h * 4;
                for (int i = 0; i < cp; i += 4) {
                    float a = sp[i + 3] / 255.0f;
                    sp[i] = (unsigned char)((float)sp[i] * a);
                    sp[i + 1] = sp[i];
                    sp[i + 2] = sp[i];
                }

                // Save glyph image and update coordinates
                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, lx, bestHeight - ly - 1 - glyphSurface->h, glyphSurface->w, glyphSurface->h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glyphSurface->pixels);
                glyphRects[gi].x = lx;
                glyphRects[gi].y = ly;
                glyphRects[gi].z = glyphSurface->w;
                glyphRects[gi].w = glyphSurface->h;

                SDL_FreeSurface(glyphSurface);
                glyphSurface = nullptr;

                lx += glyphRects[gi].z + padding;
            }
            ly += _fontHeight + padding;
        }

        // Draw the unsupported glyph
        int rs = padding - 1;
        int* pureWhiteSquare = new int[rs * rs];
        memset(pureWhiteSquare, 0xffffffff, rs * rs * sizeof(int));
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, rs, rs, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pureWhiteSquare);
        delete[] pureWhiteSquare;
        pureWhiteSquare = nullptr;

        // Set some texture parameters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Create spriteBatch glyphs
        _glyphs = new CharGlyph[_regLength + 1];
        for (i = 0; i < _regLength; i++) {
            _glyphs[i].character = (char)(cs + i);
            std::cout << _glyphs[i].character << std::endl;
            _glyphs[i].size = glm::vec2(glyphRects[i].z, glyphRects[i].w);
            _glyphs[i].uvRect = glm::vec4(
                (float)glyphRects[i].x / (float)bestWidth,
                (float)glyphRects[i].y / (float)bestHeight,
                (float)glyphRects[i].z / (float)bestWidth,
                (float)glyphRects[i].w / (float)bestHeight
                );
        }
        _glyphs[_regLength].character = ' ';
        _glyphs[_regLength].size = _glyphs[0].size;
        _glyphs[_regLength].uvRect = glm::vec4(0, 0, (float)rs / (float)bestWidth, (float)rs / (float)bestHeight);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        delete[] glyphRects;
        delete[] bestPartition;
        TTF_CloseFont(f);
    }

    void SpriteFont::dispose() {
        if (_texID != 0) {
            glDeleteTextures(1, &_texID);
            _texID = 0;
        }
        if (_glyphs) {
            delete[] _glyphs;
            _glyphs = nullptr;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int>* SpriteFont::createRows(glm::ivec4* rects, int rectsLength, int r, int padding, int& w) {
        // Blank initialize
        std::vector<int>* l = new std::vector<int>[r]();
        int* cw = new int[r]();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            cw[i] = padding;
        }

        // Loop through all glyphs
        for (int i = 0; i < rectsLength; i++) {
            // Find row for placement
            int ri = 0;
            for (int rii = 1; rii < r; rii++)
                if (cw[rii] < cw[ri]) ri = rii;

            // Add width to that row
            cw[ri] += rects[i].z + padding;

            // Add glyph to the row list
            l[ri].push_back(i);
        }

        // Find the max width
        w = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            if (cw[i] > w) w = cw[i];
        }

        return l;
    }

    glm::vec2 SpriteFont::measure(const char* s) {
        glm::vec2 size(0, _fontHeight);
        float cw = 0;
        for (int si = 0; s[si] != 0; si++) {
            char c = s[si];
            if (s[si] == '\n') {
                size.y += _fontHeight;
                if (size.x < cw)
                    size.x = cw;
                cw = 0;
            }
            else {
                // Check for correct glyph
                int gi = c - _regStart;
                if (gi < 0 || gi >= _regLength)
                    gi = _regLength;
                cw += _glyphs[gi].size.x;
            }
        }
        if (size.x < cw)
            size.x = cw;
        return size;
    }

    void SpriteFont::draw(SpriteBatch& batch, const char* s, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 scaling,
        float depth, ColorRGBA8 tint, Justification just /* = Justification::LEFT */) {
        glm::vec2 tp = position;
        // Apply justification
        if (just == Justification::MIDDLE) {
            tp.x -= measure(s).x * scaling.x / 2;
        }
        else if (just == Justification::RIGHT) {
            tp.x -= measure(s).x * scaling.x;
        }
        for (int si = 0; s[si] != 0; si++) {
            char c = s[si];
            if (s[si] == '\n') {
                tp.y += _fontHeight * scaling.y;
                tp.x = position.x;
            }
            else {
                // Check for correct glyph
                int gi = c - _regStart;
                if (gi < 0 || gi >= _regLength) gi = _regLength;
                glm::vec4 destRect(tp, _glyphs[gi].size * scaling);
                //if (c == '\u00E4') std::cout << _glyphs[gi].uvRect.x << " " << _glyphs[gi].uvRect.y << " " << _glyphs[gi].uvRect.z << " " << _glyphs[gi].uvRect.w << std::endl;
                batch.draw(destRect, _glyphs[gi].uvRect, _texID, depth, tint);
                tp.x += _glyphs[gi].size.x * scaling.x;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope, that anyone can help me...

Comment: "but because I'm German the program should support chars up to 154." wrong. it should be using unicode to start with. also "i can't get this to work" is not an error description. what should it do, how should it do that and why doesn't it?

Comment: @nonchip, sry edited it...